# Substituir string com regex em python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex, replace

Tenho um código que ele substitui determinadas string por espaço em branco

```
    dados = '[{"Id":12345,"Date":"2018-11-03T00:00:00","Quality":"Goodão","Name":"X","Description":null,"Url":"x.com.br/qweqwe","ParseUrl":"x-art","Status":"Ativa","Surveys":0,"KeySearch":"x Art","QualityId":3,"Type":"Tecnology"},{"Id":12346,"Date":"2018-11-03T00:00:00","Quality":"Good","Name":"YYy","Description":"Lorem Ipsum has been the industrys standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.","Url":"https://www.y.com.br/sdfsfs","ParseUrl":"y beautiful","Status":"Ativa","Surveys":0,"KeySearch":"y like","QualityId":3,"Type":"Tecnology"},{"Id":12347,"Date":"2018-11-03T00:00:00","Quçality":"Pending","Name":"z Z","Description":"Richard McClintock, a Latin professor at Hampden-Sydney College in Virginia, looked up one of the more obscure Latin words, consectetur","Url":"http://www.z.com.br/asdasdas","ParseUrl":null,"Status":"Ativa","Surveys":112,"KeySearch":"z plant","QualityId":4,"Type":"Agro"},{"Id":12335,"Date":"2018-11-03T00:00:00","Quality":"óéGood","Name":"J","Description":null,"Url":"www.j.com.br","ParseUrl":"x-art","Status":"Ativa","Surveys":0,"KeySearch":"x Art","QualityId":3,"Type":"Tecnology"},{"Id":12332,"Date":"2018-11-03T00:00:00","Quality":"óéGood","Name":"J","Description":null,"Url":"www.j.com.br/","ParseUrl":"x-art","Status":"Ativa","Surveys":0,"KeySearch":"x Art","QualityId":3,"Type":"Tecnology"}]'
    dados = dados.replace('http://', '')
    dados = dados.replace('https://', '')
    print(dados)
```

Resultado:

```
[{"Id":12345,"Date":"2018-11-03T00:00:00","Quality":"Good�o","Name":"X","Description":null,"Url":"x.com.br/qweqwe","ParseUrl":"x-art","Status":"Ativa","Surveys":0,"KeySearch":"x Art","QualityId":3,"Type":"Tecnology"},{"Id":12346,"Date":"2018-11-03T00:00:00","Quality":"Good","Name":"YYy","Description":"Lorem Ipsum has been the industrys standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.","Url":"www.y.com.br/sdfsfs","ParseUrl":"y beautiful","Status":"Ativa","Surveys":0,"KeySearch":"y like","QualityId":3,"Type":"Tecnology"},{"Id":12347,"Date":"2018-11-03T00:00:00","Qu�ality":"Pending","Name":"z Z","Description":"Richard McClintock, a Latin professor at Hampden-Sydney College in Virginia, looked up one of the more obscure Latin words, consectetur","Url":"www.z.com.br/asdasdas","ParseUrl":null,"Status":"Ativa","Surveys":112,"KeySearch":"z plant","QualityId":4,"Type":"Agro"},{"Id":12335,"Date":"2018-11-03T00:00:00","Quality":"��Good","Name":"J","Description":null,"Url":"www.j.com.br","ParseUrl":"x-art","Status":"Ativa","Surveys":0,"KeySearch":"x Art","QualityId":3,"Type":"Tecnology"},{"Id":12332,"Date":"2018-11-03T00:00:00","Quality":"��Good","Name":"J","Description":null,"Url":"www.j.com.br/","ParseUrl":"x-art","Status":"Ativa","Surveys":0,"KeySearch":"x Art","QualityId":3,"Type":"Tecnology"}]
```

Nessa situação o resultado acontece como esperado, porém quando eu preciso utilizar uma regex para fazer o replace eu não consigo (já tentei de várias formas).

Como é possível ver abaixo, ele apenas substitui o primeiro elemento e sobrescreve toda a variável dados, veja:

```
dados = re.sub(re.compile('(/.*)', re.MULTILINE), '', dados)
print(dados)
```

Resultado:

```
[{"Id":12345,"Date":"2018-11-03T00:00:00","Quality":"Good�o","Name":"X","Description":null,"Url":"x.com.br
```

Entendo o que aconteceu, porém desejo saber se existe uma forma de substituir utilizando regex, semelhante a função `replace`.

O objetivo é deixar apenas o domínio e tirar todo o lixo, exemplo: 
para `x.com.br/qweqwe`, considero "lixo" o trecho `/qweqwe`, pois apenas o `x.com.br` é importante.

Comment: Embora seja possível com regex, não seria melhor usar as funções específicas para parsing de URL?  https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html

Comment: hkotsubo, é necessário utilizar o replace pois preciso preservar o restante dos dados na variável, assim como disse ao nosklo

Comment: Poderia **[edit]** a pergunta e colocar exemplos de valores que devem ser preservados? De qualquer forma, acho que daria para fazer um `split` em dados e tratar as URLs uma a uma, e depois você junta de novo com `join`. Mas para ter certeza, só vendo alguns exemplos mesmo...

Comment: hkotsubo adicionei mais exemplos, no json de exemplo possui apenas 3 exemplos, mas existe uma infinidade de registros. Obrigado

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sua string de entrada é um JSON, então é melhor usar as ferramentas corretas para manipular estes dados. Você pode usar o [módulo `json`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html) e em seguida manipular a URL com [`urllib.parse`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html#module-urllib.parse):

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import re
import json
import urllib.parse

dados = '[{"Id":12345,"Date":"2018-11-03T00:00:00","Quality":"Goodão","Name":"X","Description":null,"Url":"x.com.br/qweqwe","ParseUrl":"x-art","Status":"Ativa","Surveys":0,"KeySearch":"x Art","QualityId":3,"Type":"Tecnology"},{"Id":12346,"Date":"2018-11-03T00:00:00","Quality":"Good","Name":"YYy","Description":"Lorem Ipsum has been the industrys standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.","Url":"https://www.y.com.br/sdfsfs","ParseUrl":"y beautiful","Status":"Ativa","Surveys":0,"KeySearch":"y like","QualityId":3,"Type":"Tecnology"},{"Id":12347,"Date":"2018-11-03T00:00:00","Quçality":"Pending","Name":"z Z","Description":"Richard McClintock, a Latin professor at Hampden-Sydney College in Virginia, looked up one of the more obscure Latin words, consectetur","Url":"http://www.z.com.br/asdasdas","ParseUrl":null,"Status":"Ativa","Surveys":112,"KeySearch":"z plant","QualityId":4,"Type":"Agro"},{"Id":12335,"Date":"2018-11-03T00:00:00","Quality":"óéGood","Name":"J","Description":null,"Url":"www.j.com.br","ParseUrl":"x-art","Status":"Ativa","Surveys":0,"KeySearch":"x Art","QualityId":3,"Type":"Tecnology"},{"Id":12332,"Date":"2018-11-03T00:00:00","Quality":"óéGood","Name":"J","Description":null,"Url":"www.j.com.br/","ParseUrl":"x-art","Status":"Ativa","Surveys":0,"KeySearch":"x Art","QualityId":3,"Type":"Tecnology"}]'

# converter a string para JSON
jsondata = json.loads(dados)

# regex para verificar se a URL tem o protocolo
r = re.compile(r"^(https?|ftp)://")

# substituir somente o campo URL
for d in jsondata:
    url = d['Url']
    # se não tem o protocolo, adiciona qualquer um, apenas para o parsing ser feito corretamente
    if not r.match(url):
        url = "http://"+ url
    d['Url'] = urllib.parse.urlparse(url).netloc

# converter JSON para string
dados = json.dumps(jsondata, ensure_ascii=False)
print(dados)
```

A saída é:

> ```
> [{"Id": 12345, "Date": "2018-11-03T00:00:00", "Quality": "Goodão", "Name": "X", "Description": null, "Url": "x.com.br", "ParseUrl": "x-art", "Status": "Ativa", "Surveys": 0, "KeySearch": "x Art", "QualityId": 3, "Type": "Tecnology"}, {"Id": 12346, "Date": "2018-11-03T00:00:00", "Quality": "Good", "Name": "YYy", "Description": "Lorem Ipsum has been the industrys standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.", "Url": "www.y.com.br", "ParseUrl": "y beautiful", "Status": "Ativa", "Surveys": 0, "KeySearch": "y like", "QualityId": 3, "Type": "Tecnology"}, {"Id": 12347, "Date": "2018-11-03T00:00:00", "Quçality": "Pending", "Name": "z Z", "Description": "Richard McClintock, a Latin professor at Hampden-Sydney College in Virginia, looked up one of the more obscure Latin words, consectetur", "Url": "www.z.com.br", "ParseUrl": null, "Status": "Ativa", "Surveys": 112, "KeySearch": "z plant", "QualityId": 4, "Type": "Agro"}, {"Id": 12335, "Date": "2018-11-03T00:00:00", "Quality": "óéGood", "Name": "J", "Description": null, "Url": "www.j.com.br", "ParseUrl": "x-art", "Status": "Ativa", "Surveys": 0, "KeySearch": "x Art", "QualityId": 3, "Type": "Tecnology"}, {"Id": 12332, "Date": "2018-11-03T00:00:00", "Quality": "óéGood", "Name": "J", "Description": null, "Url": "www.j.com.br", "ParseUrl": "x-art", "Status": "Ativa", "Surveys": 0, "KeySearch": "x Art", "QualityId": 3, "Type": "Tecnology"}]
> ```

Repare que as chaves estão em ordem diferente da entrada, pois o JSON é definido como um [*unordered set of name/value pairs*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4515863) (um conjunto de pares chave/valor **sem ordem**). Por isso a ordem não é garantida.

---

Outros detalhes:

Eu usei uma regex (usando o [módulo `re`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/re.html)) para verificar se a URL não tem o protocolo (o `http://` no início, por exemplo). Eu usei `^(https?|ftp)://`, que significa:

- `^`: início da string
- `https?`: o texto "http" ou "https" (o `s?` indica que a letra "s" é opcional)
- `ftp`: o texto "ftp""
- `|`: significa **ou**. Então `(https?|ftp)` quer dizer que o trecho pode ser http, https, ou ftp. Em seguida temos os caracteres `://`

Adicione mais protocolos conforme necessário, todos separados por `|`. Por exemplo: `^(https?|ftp|telnet|mailto)://` (para verificar http/https, ftp, telnet ou mailto).

Se a URL não corresponde a este padrão (ou seja, se não tem o protocolo), eu adiciono um protocolo qualquer para que o parsing seja feito (caso contrário `urlparse` fica com o `netloc` vazio). Como você não vai usar o protocolo para nada, tanto faz qual é colocado.

E para os caracteres especiais, você pode forçar o script a usar um encoding específico, como eu fiz na primeira linha (`# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-`). E no método `dumps`, passe o valor do parâmetro `ensure_ascii` igual a `False` - o *default* é `True`, o que faz com que caracteres especiais [não sejam exibidos corretamente](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/json.html#basic-usage).

---

#### Se quiser manter a mesma ordem

Mas se por acaso você precisa manter exatamente a mesma ordem das chaves, aí o jeito é usar regex mesmo. Um jeito é verificar o trecho `"Url":"..."` e obter a URL que está aí. Em seguida, usamos `urllib.parse` para substituir a URL pela parte que você precisa.

E eu também uso a mesma regex do exemplo anterior para verificar se a URL tem o protocolo, e adiciono "http://" caso não tenha.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import urllib.parse
import re

dados = '[{"Id":12345,"Date":"2018-11-03T00:00:00","Quality":"Goodão","Name":"X","Description":null,"Url":"x.com.br/qweqwe","ParseUrl":"x-art","Status":"Ativa","Surveys":0,"KeySearch":"x Art","QualityId":3,"Type":"Tecnology"},{"Id":12346,"Date":"2018-11-03T00:00:00","Quality":"Good","Name":"YYy","Description":"Lorem Ipsum has been the industrys standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.","Url":"https://www.y.com.br/sdfsfs","ParseUrl":"y beautiful","Status":"Ativa","Surveys":0,"KeySearch":"y like","QualityId":3,"Type":"Tecnology"},{"Id":12347,"Date":"2018-11-03T00:00:00","Quçality":"Pending","Name":"z Z","Description":"Richard McClintock, a Latin professor at Hampden-Sydney College in Virginia, looked up one of the more obscure Latin words, consectetur","Url":"http://www.z.com.br/asdasdas","ParseUrl":null,"Status":"Ativa","Surveys":112,"KeySearch":"z plant","QualityId":4,"Type":"Agro"},{"Id":12335,"Date":"2018-11-03T00:00:00","Quality":"óéGood","Name":"J","Description":null,"Url":"www.j.com.br","ParseUrl":"x-art","Status":"Ativa","Surveys":0,"KeySearch":"x Art","QualityId":3,"Type":"Tecnology"},{"Id":12332,"Date":"2018-11-03T00:00:00","Quality":"óéGood","Name":"J","Description":null,"Url":"www.j.com.br/","ParseUrl":"x-art","Status":"Ativa","Surveys":0,"KeySearch":"x Art","QualityId":3,"Type":"Tecnology"}]'

# regex para verificar se a URL tem o protocolo
r = re.compile(r"^(https?|ftp)://")

dados = re.sub(r'(?<="Url":")[^"]+(?=")', lambda m: urllib.parse.urlparse(m.group(0) if r.match(m.group(0)) else "http://" + m.group(0)).netloc, dados)
print(dados)
```

A saída é:

> ```
> [{"Id":12345,"Date":"2018-11-03T00:00:00","Quality":"Goodão","Name":"X","Description":null,"Url":"x.com.br","ParseUrl":"x-art","Status":"Ativa","Surveys":0,"KeySearch":"x Art","QualityId":3,"Type":"Tecnology"},{"Id":12346,"Date":"2018-11-03T00:00:00","Quality":"Good","Name":"YYy","Description":"Lorem Ipsum has been the industrys standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.","Url":"www.y.com.br","ParseUrl":"y beautiful","Status":"Ativa","Surveys":0,"KeySearch":"y like","QualityId":3,"Type":"Tecnology"},{"Id":12347,"Date":"2018-11-03T00:00:00","Quçality":"Pending","Name":"z Z","Description":"Richard McClintock, a Latin professor at Hampden-Sydney College in Virginia, looked up one of the more obscure Latin words, consectetur","Url":"www.z.com.br","ParseUrl":null,"Status":"Ativa","Surveys":112,"KeySearch":"z plant","QualityId":4,"Type":"Agro"},{"Id":12335,"Date":"2018-11-03T00:00:00","Quality":"óéGood","Name":"J","Description":null,"Url":"www.j.com.br","ParseUrl":"x-art","Status":"Ativa","Surveys":0,"KeySearch":"x Art","QualityId":3,"Type":"Tecnology"},{"Id":12332,"Date":"2018-11-03T00:00:00","Quality":"óéGood","Name":"J","Description":null,"Url":"www.j.com.br","ParseUrl":"x-art","Status":"Ativa","Surveys":0,"KeySearch":"x Art","QualityId":3,"Type":"Tecnology"}]
> ```

Vale lembrar que neste caso não estamos usando as ferramentas mais adequadas, pois a regex não quer saber se a string é realmente um JSON bem formado, ela apenas procura pelo trecho indicado e faz a substituição.

---

Uma breve explicação da regex:

`(?<="Url":")` e `(?=")` são, respectivamente, [um *lookbehind* e um *lookahead*](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html). Eles servem para verificar o que tem antes e depois de determinado trecho. Ou seja, eu quero um trecho da string que tenha `"Url":"` antes e `"` depois. Os parênteses e os caracteres `?`, `<` e `=` fazem parte da sintaxe da regex para definir este comportamento (além disso, eles não farão parte do *match*, que terá apenas o que está entre eles - no caso, a URL).

Entre o *lookbehind* e o *lookahead* temos `[^"]+`, que significa uma ou mais ocorrências (`+`) de qualquer coisa que não seja aspas (`[^"]`) - os colchetes com `^` indicam que eu não quero os caracteres que estão ali dentro, e como só tem `"`, então quer dizer que eu quero tudo que não tem aspas.

Ou seja, a regex significa: `"Url":"` seguido de um ou mais caracteres que não sejam aspas, seguido de `"`.

Depois eu uso um *lambda* para fazer a substituição. O parâmetro passado para o *lambda* é o *match* da regex (ou seja, o trecho que foi capturado). Em seguida eu uso `urllib.parse` para obter o trecho que quero da URL.

Eu optei por usar `urllib.parse` para manipular a URL por ser mais fácil (além de ser uma função dedicada para justamente tratar de URLs), pois como você pode ver pela [resposta do @nosklo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/341054/112052), uma regex para pegar trechos de URLs válidas é complicada demais para valer a pena. Por isso acabei usando uma expressão mais simples (peguei tudo que estava entre as aspas, e depois passei para `urlparse`, que pode verificar mais facilmente se de fato é uma URL).

Comment: hkotsubo Funciona corretamente sua resposta e agradeço por toda a explicação, porém ainda existe um problema, veja os "Id":12335 e "Id":12332.
Ocorre problema com a saída: "Url":"", ficando vazia pois a url não contém o protocolo e ocorre erro de caracter quando existe um especial, se transforma em um ponto de interrogação. Poderia me ajudar?
Pergunta atualizada.

Comment: @DaniloAlbergardi Atualizei a resposta, veja se agora funciona

Comment: funcionou perfeitamente, obrigado!

Answer (score 2):

O problema está na sua regex... `'(/.*)'` significa "uma barra e tudo que vier depois"!

Eu não sei o que você quer fazer... Se quer tirar o http tente usar essa regex: `r'https?://'`

EDIT: Agora que você colocou seu objetivo, acredito que a ferramenta certa não seja regexp e sim as funções específicas para url que ficam em [`urllib.parse`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html):

```
>>> import urllib.parse

>>> url = 'https://www.y.com.br/sdfsfs'
>>> print(urllib.parse.urlparse(url))
ParseResult(scheme='https', netloc='www.y.com.br', path='/sdfsfs', 
            params='', query='', fragment='')
>>> print(urllib.parse.urlparse(url).netloc)
www.y.com.br
```

Pra completar, vou deixar aqui a regexp completa para parsear urls, que realmente segue todas as regras possíveis de URL:

```
(?:http://(?:(?:(?:(?:(?:[a-zA-Z\d](?:(?:[a-zA-Z\d]|-)*[a-zA-Z\d])?)\.
)*(?:[a-zA-Z](?:(?:[a-zA-Z\d]|-)*[a-zA-Z\d])?))|(?:(?:\d+)(?:\.(?:\d+)
){3}))(?::(?:\d+))?)(?:/(?:(?:(?:(?:[a-zA-Z\d$\-_.+!*'(),]|(?:%[a-fA-F
\d]{2}))|[;:@&=])*)(?:/(?:(?:(?:[a-zA-Z\d$\-_.+!*'(),]|(?:%[a-fA-F\d]{
2}))|[;:@&=])*))*)(?:\?(?:(?:(?:[a-zA-Z\d$\-_.+!*'(),]|(?:%[a-fA-F\d]{
2}))|[;:@&=])*))?)?)|(?:ftp://(?:(?:(?:(?:(?:[a-zA-Z\d$\-_.+!*'(),]|(?
:%[a-fA-F\d]{2}))|[;?&=])*)(?::(?:(?:(?:[a-zA-Z\d$\-_.+!*'(),]|(?:%[a-
fA-F\d]{2}))|[;?&=])*))?@)?(?:(?:(?:(?:(?:[a-zA-Z\d](?:(?:[a-zA-Z\d]|-
)*[a-zA-Z\d])?)\.)*(?:[a-zA-Z](?:(?:[a-zA-Z\d]|-)*[a-zA-Z\d])?))|(?:(?
:\d+)(?:\.(?:\d+)){3}))(?::(?:\d+))?))(?:/(?:(?:(?:(?:[a-zA-Z\d$\-_.+!
*'(),]|(?:%[a-fA-F\d]{2}))|[?:@&=])*)(?:/(?:(?:(?:[a-zA-Z\d$\-_.+!*'()
,]|(?:%[a-fA-F\d]{2}))|[?:@&=])*))*)(?:;type=[AIDaid])?)?)|(?:news:(?:
(?:(?:(?:[a-zA-Z\d$\-_.+!*'(),]|(?:%[a-fA-F\d]{2}))|[;/?:&=])+@(?:(?:(
?:(?:[a-zA-Z\d](?:(?:[a-zA-Z\d]|-)*[a-zA-Z\d])?)\.)*(?:[a-zA-Z](?:(?:[
a-zA-Z\d]|-)*[a-zA-Z\d])?))|(?:(?:\d+)(?:\.(?:\d+)){3})))|(?:[a-zA-Z](
?:[a-zA-Z\d]|[_.+-])*)|\*))|(?:nntp://(?:(?:(?:(?:(?:[a-zA-Z\d](?:(?:[
a-zA-Z\d]|-)*[a-zA-Z\d])?)\.)*(?:[a-zA-Z](?:(?:[a-zA-Z\d]|-)*[a-zA-Z\d
])?))|(?:(?:\d+)(?:\.(?:\d+)){3}))(?::(?:\d+))?)/(?:[a-zA-Z](?:[a-zA-Z
\d]|[_.+-])*)(?:/(?:\d+))?)|(?:telnet://(?:(?:(?:(?:(?:[a-zA-Z\d$\-_.+
!*'(),]|(?:%[a-fA-F\d]{2}))|[;?&=])*)(?::(?:(?:(?:[a-zA-Z\d$\-_.+!*'()
,]|(?:%[a-fA-F\d]{2}))|[;?&=])*))?@)?(?:(?:(?:(?:(?:[a-zA-Z\d](?:(?:[a
-zA-Z\d]|-)*[a-zA-Z\d])?)\.)*(?:[a-zA-Z](?:(?:[a-zA-Z\d]|-)*[a-zA-Z\d]
)?))|(?:(?:\d+)(?:\.(?:\d+)){3}))(?::(?:\d+))?))/?)|(?:gopher://(?:(?:
(?:(?:(?:[a-zA-Z\d](?:(?:[a-zA-Z\d]|-)*[a-zA-Z\d])?)\.)*(?:[a-zA-Z](?:
(?:[a-zA-Z\d]|-)*[a-zA-Z\d])?))|(?:(?:\d+)(?:\.(?:\d+)){3}))(?::(?:\d+
))?)(?:/(?:[a-zA-Z\d$\-_.+!*'(),;/?:@&=]|(?:%[a-fA-F\d]{2}))(?:(?:(?:[
a-zA-Z\d$\-_.+!*'(),;/?:@&=]|(?:%[a-fA-F\d]{2}))*)(?:%09(?:(?:(?:[a-zA
-Z\d$\-_.+!*'(),]|(?:%[a-fA-F\d]{2}))|[;:@&=])*)(?:%09(?:(?:[a-zA-Z\d$
\-_.+!*'(),;/?:@&=]|(?:%[a-fA-F\d]{2}))*))?)?)?)?)|(?:wais://(?:(?:(?:
(?:(?:[a-zA-Z\d](?:(?:[a-zA-Z\d]|-)*[a-zA-Z\d])?)\.)*(?:[a-zA-Z](?:(?:
[a-zA-Z\d]|-)*[a-zA-Z\d])?))|(?:(?:\d+)(?:\.(?:\d+)){3}))(?::(?:\d+))?
)/(?:(?:[a-zA-Z\d$\-_.+!*'(),]|(?:%[a-fA-F\d]{2}))*)(?:(?:/(?:(?:[a-zA
-Z\d$\-_.+!*'(),]|(?:%[a-fA-F\d]{2}))*)/(?:(?:[a-zA-Z\d$\-_.+!*'(),]|(
?:%[a-fA-F\d]{2}))*))|\?(?:(?:(?:[a-zA-Z\d$\-_.+!*'(),]|(?:%[a-fA-F\d]
{2}))|[;:@&=])*))?)|(?:mailto:(?:(?:[a-zA-Z\d$\-_.+!*'(),;/?:@&=]|(?:%
[a-fA-F\d]{2}))+))|(?:file://(?:(?:(?:(?:(?:[a-zA-Z\d](?:(?:[a-zA-Z\d]
|-)*[a-zA-Z\d])?)\.)*(?:[a-zA-Z](?:(?:[a-zA-Z\d]|-)*[a-zA-Z\d])?))|(?:
(?:\d+)(?:\.(?:\d+)){3}))|localhost)?/(?:(?:(?:(?:[a-zA-Z\d$\-_.+!*'()
,]|(?:%[a-fA-F\d]{2}))|[?:@&=])*)(?:/(?:(?:(?:[a-zA-Z\d$\-_.+!*'(),]|(
?:%[a-fA-F\d]{2}))|[?:@&=])*))*))|(?:prospero://(?:(?:(?:(?:(?:[a-zA-Z
\d](?:(?:[a-zA-Z\d]|-)*[a-zA-Z\d])?)\.)*(?:[a-zA-Z](?:(?:[a-zA-Z\d]|-)
*[a-zA-Z\d])?))|(?:(?:\d+)(?:\.(?:\d+)){3}))(?::(?:\d+))?)/(?:(?:(?:(?
:[a-zA-Z\d$\-_.+!*'(),]|(?:%[a-fA-F\d]{2}))|[?:@&=])*)(?:/(?:(?:(?:[a-
zA-Z\d$\-_.+!*'(),]|(?:%[a-fA-F\d]{2}))|[?:@&=])*))*)(?:(?:;(?:(?:(?:[
a-zA-Z\d$\-_.+!*'(),]|(?:%[a-fA-F\d]{2}))|[?:@&])*)=(?:(?:(?:[a-zA-Z\d
$\-_.+!*'(),]|(?:%[a-fA-F\d]{2}))|[?:@&])*)))*)|(?:ldap://(?:(?:(?:(?:
(?:(?:[a-zA-Z\d](?:(?:[a-zA-Z\d]|-)*[a-zA-Z\d])?)\.)*(?:[a-zA-Z](?:(?:
[a-zA-Z\d]|-)*[a-zA-Z\d])?))|(?:(?:\d+)(?:\.(?:\d+)){3}))(?::(?:\d+))?
))?/(?:(?:(?:(?:(?:(?:(?:[a-zA-Z\d]|%(?:3\d|[46][a-fA-F\d]|[57][Aa\d])
)|(?:%20))+|(?:OID|oid)\.(?:(?:\d+)(?:\.(?:\d+))*))(?:(?:%0[Aa])?(?:%2
0)*)=(?:(?:%0[Aa])?(?:%20)*))?(?:(?:[a-zA-Z\d$\-_.+!*'(),]|(?:%[a-fA-F
\d]{2}))*))(?:(?:(?:%0[Aa])?(?:%20)*)\+(?:(?:%0[Aa])?(?:%20)*)(?:(?:(?
:(?:(?:[a-zA-Z\d]|%(?:3\d|[46][a-fA-F\d]|[57][Aa\d]))|(?:%20))+|(?:OID
|oid)\.(?:(?:\d+)(?:\.(?:\d+))*))(?:(?:%0[Aa])?(?:%20)*)=(?:(?:%0[Aa])
?(?:%20)*))?(?:(?:[a-zA-Z\d$\-_.+!*'(),]|(?:%[a-fA-F\d]{2}))*)))*)(?:(
?:(?:(?:%0[Aa])?(?:%20)*)(?:[;,])(?:(?:%0[Aa])?(?:%20)*))(?:(?:(?:(?:(
?:(?:[a-zA-Z\d]|%(?:3\d|[46][a-fA-F\d]|[57][Aa\d]))|(?:%20))+|(?:OID|o
id)\.(?:(?:\d+)(?:\.(?:\d+))*))(?:(?:%0[Aa])?(?:%20)*)=(?:(?:%0[Aa])?(
?:%20)*))?(?:(?:[a-zA-Z\d$\-_.+!*'(),]|(?:%[a-fA-F\d]{2}))*))(?:(?:(?:
%0[Aa])?(?:%20)*)\+(?:(?:%0[Aa])?(?:%20)*)(?:(?:(?:(?:(?:[a-zA-Z\d]|%(
?:3\d|[46][a-fA-F\d]|[57][Aa\d]))|(?:%20))+|(?:OID|oid)\.(?:(?:\d+)(?:
\.(?:\d+))*))(?:(?:%0[Aa])?(?:%20)*)=(?:(?:%0[Aa])?(?:%20)*))?(?:(?:[a
-zA-Z\d$\-_.+!*'(),]|(?:%[a-fA-F\d]{2}))*)))*))*(?:(?:(?:%0[Aa])?(?:%2
0)*)(?:[;,])(?:(?:%0[Aa])?(?:%20)*))?)(?:\?(?:(?:(?:(?:[a-zA-Z\d$\-_.+
!*'(),]|(?:%[a-fA-F\d]{2}))+)(?:,(?:(?:[a-zA-Z\d$\-_.+!*'(),]|(?:%[a-f
A-F\d]{2}))+))*)?)(?:\?(?:base|one|sub)(?:\?(?:((?:[a-zA-Z\d$\-_.+!*'(
),;/?:@&=]|(?:%[a-fA-F\d]{2}))+)))?)?)?)|(?:(?:z39\.50[rs])://(?:(?:(?
:(?:(?:[a-zA-Z\d](?:(?:[a-zA-Z\d]|-)*[a-zA-Z\d])?)\.)*(?:[a-zA-Z](?:(?
:[a-zA-Z\d]|-)*[a-zA-Z\d])?))|(?:(?:\d+)(?:\.(?:\d+)){3}))(?::(?:\d+))
?)(?:/(?:(?:(?:[a-zA-Z\d$\-_.+!*'(),]|(?:%[a-fA-F\d]{2}))+)(?:\+(?:(?:
[a-zA-Z\d$\-_.+!*'(),]|(?:%[a-fA-F\d]{2}))+))*(?:\?(?:(?:[a-zA-Z\d$\-_
.+!*'(),]|(?:%[a-fA-F\d]{2}))+))?)?(?:;esn=(?:(?:[a-zA-Z\d$\-_.+!*'(),
]|(?:%[a-fA-F\d]{2}))+))?(?:;rs=(?:(?:[a-zA-Z\d$\-_.+!*'(),]|(?:%[a-fA
-F\d]{2}))+)(?:\+(?:(?:[a-zA-Z\d$\-_.+!*'(),]|(?:%[a-fA-F\d]{2}))+))*)
?))|(?:cid:(?:(?:(?:[a-zA-Z\d$\-_.+!*'(),]|(?:%[a-fA-F\d]{2}))|[;?:@&=
])*))|(?:mid:(?:(?:(?:[a-zA-Z\d$\-_.+!*'(),]|(?:%[a-fA-F\d]{2}))|[;?:@
&=])*)(?:/(?:(?:(?:[a-zA-Z\d$\-_.+!*'(),]|(?:%[a-fA-F\d]{2}))|[;?:@&=]
)*))?)|(?:vemmi://(?:(?:(?:(?:(?:[a-zA-Z\d](?:(?:[a-zA-Z\d]|-)*[a-zA-Z
\d])?)\.)*(?:[a-zA-Z](?:(?:[a-zA-Z\d]|-)*[a-zA-Z\d])?))|(?:(?:\d+)(?:\
.(?:\d+)){3}))(?::(?:\d+))?)(?:/(?:(?:(?:[a-zA-Z\d$\-_.+!*'(),]|(?:%[a
-fA-F\d]{2}))|[/?:@&=])*)(?:(?:;(?:(?:(?:[a-zA-Z\d$\-_.+!*'(),]|(?:%[a
-fA-F\d]{2}))|[/?:@&])*)=(?:(?:(?:[a-zA-Z\d$\-_.+!*'(),]|(?:%[a-fA-F\d
]{2}))|[/?:@&])*))*))?)|(?:imap://(?:(?:(?:(?:(?:(?:(?:[a-zA-Z\d$\-_.+
!*'(),]|(?:%[a-fA-F\d]{2}))|[&=~])+)(?:(?:;[Aa][Uu][Tt][Hh]=(?:\*|(?:(
?:(?:[a-zA-Z\d$\-_.+!*'(),]|(?:%[a-fA-F\d]{2}))|[&=~])+))))?)|(?:(?:;[
Aa][Uu][Tt][Hh]=(?:\*|(?:(?:(?:[a-zA-Z\d$\-_.+!*'(),]|(?:%[a-fA-F\d]{2
}))|[&=~])+)))(?:(?:(?:(?:[a-zA-Z\d$\-_.+!*'(),]|(?:%[a-fA-F\d]{2}))|[
&=~])+))?))@)?(?:(?:(?:(?:(?:[a-zA-Z\d](?:(?:[a-zA-Z\d]|-)*[a-zA-Z\d])
?)\.)*(?:[a-zA-Z](?:(?:[a-zA-Z\d]|-)*[a-zA-Z\d])?))|(?:(?:\d+)(?:\.(?:
\d+)){3}))(?::(?:\d+))?))/(?:(?:(?:(?:(?:(?:[a-zA-Z\d$\-_.+!*'(),]|(?:
%[a-fA-F\d]{2}))|[&=~:@/])+)?;[Tt][Yy][Pp][Ee]=(?:[Ll](?:[Ii][Ss][Tt]|
[Ss][Uu][Bb])))|(?:(?:(?:(?:[a-zA-Z\d$\-_.+!*'(),]|(?:%[a-fA-F\d]{2}))
|[&=~:@/])+)(?:\?(?:(?:(?:[a-zA-Z\d$\-_.+!*'(),]|(?:%[a-fA-F\d]{2}))|[
&=~:@/])+))?(?:(?:;[Uu][Ii][Dd][Vv][Aa][Ll][Ii][Dd][Ii][Tt][Yy]=(?:[1-
9]\d*)))?)|(?:(?:(?:(?:[a-zA-Z\d$\-_.+!*'(),]|(?:%[a-fA-F\d]{2}))|[&=~
:@/])+)(?:(?:;[Uu][Ii][Dd][Vv][Aa][Ll][Ii][Dd][Ii][Tt][Yy]=(?:[1-9]\d*
)))?(?:/;[Uu][Ii][Dd]=(?:[1-9]\d*))(?:(?:/;[Ss][Ee][Cc][Tt][Ii][Oo][Nn
]=(?:(?:(?:[a-zA-Z\d$\-_.+!*'(),]|(?:%[a-fA-F\d]{2}))|[&=~:@/])+)))?))
)?)|(?:nfs:(?:(?://(?:(?:(?:(?:(?:[a-zA-Z\d](?:(?:[a-zA-Z\d]|-)*[a-zA-
Z\d])?)\.)*(?:[a-zA-Z](?:(?:[a-zA-Z\d]|-)*[a-zA-Z\d])?))|(?:(?:\d+)(?:
\.(?:\d+)){3}))(?::(?:\d+))?)(?:(?:/(?:(?:(?:(?:(?:[a-zA-Z\d\$\-_.!~*'
(),])|(?:%[a-fA-F\d]{2})|[:@&=+])*)(?:/(?:(?:(?:[a-zA-Z\d\$\-_.!~*'(),
])|(?:%[a-fA-F\d]{2})|[:@&=+])*))*)?)))?)|(?:/(?:(?:(?:(?:(?:[a-zA-Z\d
\$\-_.!~*'(),])|(?:%[a-fA-F\d]{2})|[:@&=+])*)(?:/(?:(?:(?:[a-zA-Z\d\$\
-_.!~*'(),])|(?:%[a-fA-F\d]{2})|[:@&=+])*))*)?))|(?:(?:(?:(?:(?:[a-zA-
Z\d\$\-_.!~*'(),])|(?:%[a-fA-F\d]{2})|[:@&=+])*)(?:/(?:(?:(?:[a-zA-Z\d
\$\-_.!~*'(),])|(?:%[a-fA-F\d]{2})|[:@&=+])*))*)?)))
```

Comment: nosklo Atualizei a dúvida colocando um objetivo mais claro. Eu faço a eliminação do http no primeiro trecho de código, o problema é quando preciso remover os caracteres e a barra que não são pertinentes ao domínio

Comment: a sua sugestão realmente funciona, porém ainda preciso fazer o replace, por 2 motivos: 1º Quando aplica na variável "dados", como tem mais de 1 url ele não entende que precisa retornar todos os domínios. 2º Eu preciso posteriormente fazer a consulta na variável "dados", essa variável contem muitas outras informações que precisam ser preservadas, no exemplo informado é apenas um trecho da variável "dados". Obrigado por enquanto, consegue me ajudar resolver isso com replace?